# how to access variables in xsl file from an xsl:template in another xsl file

Tags: xslt

in home.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/Screen">
        <xsl:variable name="field" select="ListOfNames[@group='1']/*[name() != 'StaticLabel']"/>

.....

    <xsl:call-template name="SecondaryTemplate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="radiofield" select="$field"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

in another file: base.xsl

```
<xsl:template name="SecondaryTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="radiofield"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$radiofield">
      <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
       <xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Is this the right way to access the `field` values defined in `home.xsl` from `SecondaryTemplate`? For some reason whenever the output of `xsl:text` keeps coming up empty.

However, when i do a 'xsl:text' in `home.xsl`, i am able to get the contents of `field`. I dont have direct access to the raw xml as thats confidential...just able to parse the contents and print them out.

Comment: If you xsl:text $radioField, does it have a value?  Then add xsl:text inside you for-each loop so you know what you are iterating over.

Comment: yes $radiofields have value as i see other xsl pages calling the same data location="ListOfNamesEtc"...and after generation, we do see the JSP pages having output. i just find it odd that on home.xsl when i call the same data location, it gives me no output...